# regex: consecutive match failure

Tags: python, regex

Using the regular expression

```
[^a-zA-Z]([A-Z][&+-\/\\][A-Z](([&+-\/\\][A-Z])+[^a-zA-Z\d:]))
```

and wanting to match letters delineated by symbols, the expression achieves successful matches, but fails to properly match patterns that immediately follow correct matches. Note that it is case insensitive in execution.

For instance in the example

> pizza a.b.c C/A/R/L about R/O/F/L s

a.b.c and R/O/F/L are correctly matched, but C/A/R/L is only partially matched (A/R/L). How can this be fixed?

Below is a regex101 mockup: but confusingly it doesn't seem to exhibit the same sort of behaviour as I am otherwise seeing.

https://www.regex101.com/r/zV8wI0/1

Comment: Try [`\b[a-zA-Z](?:[./][A-Za-z])*\b`](https://www.regex101.com/r/aQ0sU0/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is the correct answer (needs a little bit of editing for my purposes, but answers the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[a-zA-Z](?:[./][A-Za-z])*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/aQ0sU0/1)

If you do not need to match whole words, remove `\b` (word boundary).

**Explanation**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z]` - 1 letter
- `(?:[./][A-Za-z])*` - zero or more sequences (**NOTE**: if you need at least one `.` or `/`, [replace `*` with a `+`](https://www.regex101.com/r/aQ0sU0/2)) of:

  - `[./]` - a dot or a `/` symbol
  - `[A-Za-z]` - 1 letter
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

If you need to match `c.a` and `r.l` in `c.a/r.l`, you need to use something like

```
\b[a-zA-Z](?:(?:\.[A-Za-z])+|(?:/[A-Za-z])+)\b
```

See [another regex demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/aQ0sU0/3).